# Безопасность валидации на js

Tags: javascript

Проверяю форму на странице через js (все поля должны быть заполнены, только латинские буквы и тд). Такой вопрос: на сколько такая проверка безопасна и стоит ли ее продублировать на стороне сервера?

Comment: 10000000000% надо дублировать! По-другому не делается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть золотое правило - **никогда** не доверяй клиенту.
Придерживаясь его, жизнь наладится :)

Так что да, дублирование проверки необходимо, на клиенте скорее рекомендация и озвучка правил как надо поставлять данных, а не реальная проверка, т. к. любой, обладающий сниффером и мозгом, может подделать запрос вне любых клиентских проверок.